# How do I navigate to component screen from the containing screen in React Native navigation?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm creating an UserProfile screen containing a MaterialTopTabNavigator, which, in turn, consists of 2 other screen: CreatedPost and SavedPost. How do I change the displayed screen from CreatedPost to SavedPost when a button on the UserProfile screen is pressed?

The MaterialTopTabNavigator:

```
export type UserProfileTabParamList = {
    SavedPosts: undefined;
    CreatedPosts: undefined;
};

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<UserProfileTabParamList>();
```

The UserProfile screen:

```
const UserProfile: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <View className="flex">
            <View
                className="basis-2/5"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#fff" }}
            ></View>
            <Tab.Navigator
                className="basis-3/4"
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarStyle: {
                        height: 0,
                    },
                    tabBarItemStyle: { width: 100 },
                }}
            >
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="SavedPosts"
                    component={SavedPosts}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: "Saved posts",
                    }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                    name="CreatedPosts"
                    component={CreatedPosts}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: "Created posts",
                    }}
                />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </View>
    );
};
```